# unable to read/write files from web worker

Tags: web-worker, native-file-system-api-js

I am trying to read the text file (log.txt) which has already been created in my local machine and want to append text to the same file  from webworker using the filesystem api methods but unable to do so and also unable to get any error logs even though tried sending the errors by postMessage() method to the main thread using the react app wired app

//worker.js

```
*/* eslint no-restricted-globals: 0 */
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        self.requestFileSystemSync = self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync || self.requestFileSystemSync;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        self.BlobBuilder = self.BlobBuilder || self.WebKitBlobBuilder || self.MozBlobBuilder;
        try {
                var fs = self.requestFileSystemSync(self.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, onFs, onError);
        } catch (e) {
                onError(e);
        }
        function onFs(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile('/Downloads/log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {
            // Obtain the File object representing the FileEntry.
            // Use FileReader to read its contents.
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
                postMessage("file reading process", file);
                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                postMessage("file reading process result", this.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file); // Read the file as plaintext.
            }, onError);
            }, onError);
        }
        //append data to file
            function append(fs, filePath, blob) {
                postMessage("inside append functuin fs ", fs, filePath, blob);
                postMessage("inside append functuin filePath ", filePath);
                postMessage("inside append functuin blob ", blob);
                fs.root.getFile(filePath, {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry.
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); // Start write position at EOF.
                    fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
                }, onError);
            }, onError);
        }
        var bb;
        function onFs(fs) {
            postMessage("onFs function");
            bb = new Blob();
            postMessage("bb ", bb);
            bb.append("helloo world" + '\n');
            postMessage("bb after append", bb);
            append(fs, 'log.txt', bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
            postMessage("file writing", bb);
        }
        function onError(e) {
            postMessage('ERROR: ' + e.toString());
        }*
```

Comment: Hi vijesh - welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you provide more detail on exactly what happens when you execute the above code?  Does it seem to run without error, but simply not do what you intended?

Comment: as i am trying to read and append data to the existing file on my local machine, which is not working and also not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

This is using an [archaic API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystemSync). Your tag use suggests you actually meant to use the modern [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/). I recommend you give the new API a try.